# Can't print file

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, windows-7

Here's the python(3.4) code:

```
test = open('test.txt', 'r+')
test.truncate();
i = 0
stop = 99

while i <= stop:
    test.write("{:0>{}}|".format(i, len(str(stop))))
    i += 1

print(test.read())
```

It writes the file just fine, but it won't print it for some reason.

```
test = open('test.txt', 'r+')

print(test.read())
```

This prints it as expected, so I don't know where the issue may be.

Update:

Using seek(0) solved it. Can you link an explanation about it, please? I can't find it in the language's documentation.

Comment: The file pointer is at the end of the file after you write to it, so there's nothing to `read()`. Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271216/beginner-python-reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file/14276108#14276108

Comment: The docs you're looking for are that of the `io` module.  Specifically, file-like objects inherit from `IOBase`; [here is the docs on seek](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files objects point to a particular place in the file. After writing all of that stuff, your file object points to the end of the file. Reading from that point gets nothing, as expected.

```
test.seek(0)
print(test.read())
```

will read from the beginning.

Edit: a diagram. You open the file, it contains nothing.

```
''
 ^
```

you write some things to the file.

```
'hello, world\n'
               ^
```

Every time you write to the file, more stuff gets added where it's pointing.

```
'hello, world\nokay, goodbye!'
                             ^
```

Now you read the file all the way to the end!

```
''
```

It prints nothing because you started reading from the end. `seek` tells us to point someplace else in the file. Since we want to read all of it, we should start at position `0`.

```
> seek(0)
'hello, world\nokay, goodbye!'
 ^
```

Reading from the beginning reads everything.

```
hello, world
okay, goodbye!
```

Answer (score 1):

try to "rewind" the file pointer using `test.seek(0)` before the read