# Replacing words with a dictionary in text file encoded for example in UTF-8

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, file-io, runtime-error

I'm trying to open a text file and then read through it replacing certain strings with strings stored in a dictionary. Based on answers to [Replacing words in text file using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139361/9888540) and [How to search and replace text in a file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/9888540)

As like:

```
# edit print line to print (line) 
import fileinput

text = "sample file.txt"
fields = {"pattern 1": "replacement text 1", "pattern 2": "replacement text 2"}

for line in fileinput.input(text, inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    for field in fields:
        if field in line:
            line = line.replace(field, fields[field])

    print (line)
```

My file is encoding in `utf-8`.

When I run this, the console shows this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>
```

When add: `encoding = "utf8"` to `fileinput.FileInput()` its show an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

When add: `openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf8")` to `fileinput.FileInput()` it show error:

```
ValueError: FileInput cannot use an opening hook in inplace mode
```

I do not want to insert a subcode `'ignore'` ignoring errors.

I have file, dictionary and want replace values from dictionary into file like `stdout`.

Source file in `utf-8`:

```
Plain text on the line in the file.
This is a greeting to the world.
Hello world!
Here's another plain text.
And here too!
```

I want to replace the word `world` with the word `earth`.

In dictionary: `{"world": "earth"}`

Modified file in `utf-8`:

```
Plain text on the line in the file.
This is a greeting to the earth.
Hello earth!
Here's another plain text.
And here too!
```

Comment: You are using Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: I'm using Python 3. On top .py I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-. How else would it be written in Python 3? The main problem is that some older questions and answers are written in Python 2.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I was wrong and the Python 3 version doesn't have an `encoding` option. My mistake.

Comment: I presume you are using Windows?

Comment: Yep. Anaconda Spyder.

Comment: Wait, why are you using `print` **as a statement** then? That's a syntax error in Python 3. You are using Python 2, really.

Comment: Do you make the version for Python 2 and Python 3? Please.
You can edit my question for better binding.

Comment: See [In python 3.x make print work like in python 2 (as statement)](//stackoverflow.com/q/28896749) on how to make the code work in Python 2 and 3. I'll address the issues with `fileinput` in a new answer.

Comment: Oh, mea culpa. The code above is copied from the previous reply from the link (code in Python 2). In my .py is code modified for Python 3. I apologize again.

Answer (score 0):

The `fileinput` library has several problems that I [addressed in the past in a blog post](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2013/11/26/inplace-file-rewriting/); one of these is that you can't set the encoding *and* use in-place file rewriting.

The following code *can* do this, but you have to replace your `print()` calls with writes to the outgoing file object:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import io
import os


@contextmanager
def inplace(filename, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None,
            newline=None, backup_extension=None):
    """Allow for a file to be replaced with new content.

    yields a tuple of (readable, writable) file objects, where writable
    replaces readable.

    If an exception occurs, the old file is restored, removing the
    written data.

    mode should *not* use 'w', 'a' or '+'; only read-only-modes are supported.

    """

    # move existing file to backup, create new file with same permissions
    # borrowed extensively from the fileinput module
    if set(mode).intersection('wa+'):
        raise ValueError('Only read-only file modes can be used')

    backupfilename = filename + (backup_extension or os.extsep + 'bak')
    try:
        os.unlink(backupfilename)
    except os.error:
        pass
    os.rename(filename, backupfilename)
    readable = io.open(backupfilename, mode, buffering=buffering,
                       encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline=newline)
    try:
        perm = os.fstat(readable.fileno()).st_mode
    except OSError:
        writable = open(filename, 'w' + mode.replace('r', ''),
                        buffering=buffering, encoding=encoding, errors=errors,
                        newline=newline)
    else:
        os_mode = os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_TRUNC
        if hasattr(os, 'O_BINARY'):
            os_mode |= os.O_BINARY
        fd = os.open(filename, os_mode, perm)
        writable = io.open(fd, "w" + mode.replace('r', ''), buffering=buffering,
                           encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline=newline)
        try:
            if hasattr(os, 'chmod'):
                os.chmod(filename, perm)
        except OSError:
            pass
    try:
        yield readable, writable
    except Exception:
        # move backup back
        try:
            os.unlink(filename)
        except os.error:
            pass
        os.rename(backupfilename, filename)
        raise
    finally:
        readable.close()
        writable.close()
        try:
            os.unlink(backupfilename)
        except os.error:
            pass
```

So your code would look like:

import fileinput

```
text = "sample file.txt"
fields = {"pattern 1": "replacement text 1", "pattern 2": "replacement text 2"}

with inplace(text, encoding='utf8') as (infh, outfh):
    for line in infh:
        for field in fields:
            if field in line:
                line = line.replace(field, fields[field])

        outfh.write(line)
```

Note that you don't have to remove the newline now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this:

```
with open(fileName1, "r+", encoding = "utf8", newline='') as fileIn, open(fileName1, "r+", encoding = "utf8", newline='') as fileOut:
    for line in fileIn:             
        for field in fields:
            if field in line:
                line = line.replace(field, fields[field])
        fileOut.write(line)
```

**Note:** When using one file, the waste is pushed at the end of the file.
So far I have not figured out why. It does not reflect the number of replacements. (The number of replacements is greater than the number of lines of waste.)

Pseudo-mathematical:
oriA < modfA + subEnd(oriA)

I'm ready to fix it.

Edit: When I use two files, everything works correctly. Change `fileName1` in the second `open()` for `fileName2`. And change mod argument to `"w+"`.