# Unexpected read/write behaviour in 'r+' mode in python text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to perform both read and write operations in a python text file by opening it into r+ mode. However, irrespective of how many characters i read (say '**fo.read(5)**') before performing performing the write operation (say '**fo.write("random**")'), the text is written/appended at the end of the file.

```
fo = open("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/files/new.txt",'r+')
fo.read(5)
fo.write('random')
fo.close()
```

i expected the text being written ('random' in this example) to be written 6th character onward but instead got written/appended at the end of the text file. what can be the possible explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely looks like a bug.

A workaround is to explicitly seek the current file position before you write:

```
fo = open("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/files/new.txt",'r+')
fo.read(5)
fo.seek(fo.tell())
fo.write('random')
fo.close()
```

EDIT: As noted by @Blckknght, this is a known issue rooted from the C-level implementation of Windows. You can refer to [Beginner Python: Reading and writing to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271216/beginner-python-reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file) for references and discussions, although that linked question pertains to Python 2, where the behavior of the same code is different (the write either does nothing or produces an `OSError`).

Comment: I believe this is documented (mis-)behavior. On some platforms, it's undefined what happens if you both `read` and `write` a file without putting a `seek` in between.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the prior discussions and have updated my answer accordingly. I'm not marking this question as a duplicate only because that question is for Python 2, where the behavior is different.